# Watershed / drainage network analysis; floating point or integer raster for input?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, hydrology

I am a little desperate to find a solution to my problem. As I have detailed in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9237/methodology-for-creating-accurate-drainage-networks-and-catchments-from-high-re) I am unable to create a detailed drainage network (and catchments) from high resolution LiDAR data.

I think I narrowed down the issue to the use of **integer raster vs floating point raster** as the input for my analysis.

Both methods yiled dramatically different results, both methods are unasable for a detailed model. Using an integer raster as input yield a very generalized stream network and using a floating point raster yield a detailed, very disconnected and clustered stream network.

**Which type of raster should I be using for input and why?**

Current method:

1. convert to integer raster
2. fill sinks
3. flow direction
4. flow accumulation
5. stream network /stream links
6. stream order
7. watersheds (stream link input)