# Extraction of stream gradient for branched river networks

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, hydrography, watershed

At the moment I am working on the extraction of stream gradients for a large basin, as a consequence, rivers are strongly branched.So far, I read through the relevant posts on this site, but so far I am not able to apply the proposed methodologies to my problem.

I started with the common procedure of extracting the river network from the 30-by-30 m AsterDEM.  What I want to do now, is to measure the gradient of the resulting streams in fixed intervals. The interval for a river reach depends on its mean gradient, which I determined using HEC GeoHMS (the steeper the mean slope, the more often I want to sample). Thus I divided the streams in four categories.

Now, I need to divide the resulting streams in equal intervals. I wanted to make use the technique as proposed here: [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/workflow-for-determining-stream-gradient). Thus converting the stream network into a route (using the “linear referencing toolbox”) and then use route events to divide the route in reaches of equal lengths. Unfortunately I have no idea how to prepare an event table in order to divide the routes in equal intervals (e.g. one event every 100 m), especially in a branched network.

I would highly appreciate if you could guide me through the workflow, as I have no experience with the linear referencing tools!

Rafael